# Find the least positive integer $n$ such that $n$ divides $2^n - 2$ but n doesnt divide $3^n -3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the least positive integer $n$ such that $n$ divides $2^n - 2$ but $n$ doesn't divide $3^n -3$. I got that since $n$ doesn't divide $3^n -3$, therefore $n$ isn't a prime, also $n$ can't be a multiple of $4$, as $n$ divides $2^n -2$. Then I tried to find a few cases for $n= 6,9,10,14$ etc. But didn't get any solution. Any idea how to approach it?

Comment: The smallest integer appears to be 341 via brute force from python unless I did something wrong, but 341 definitely functions. The only factors are 11 and 31, and $31 = 2^5 -1$, which may be something there, also $31 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ and $11 \equiv 2 \bmod 3$. These may be helpful facts, but I don't know how to find it without brute force. I would not suggest continuing to try cases by hand.

Comment: There appear to be infinitely many qualifying values of $n$, the first four of which are $341,645,1387,1905$.

Comment: Odd composites $n$ such that $n$ divides $2^n - 2$ are Fermat pseudoprimes to base $2$ (OEIS sequence [A001567](https://oeis.org/A001567)).  It happens that the first one, $341$, is not a Fermat pseudoprime to base $3$.